# Auto-Complete in vs-code for custom button component in react using Flow.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am creating a Custom Button component in React. The basic version of the component looks something like this -

```
// @flow

type ButtonPropsType = {};
const Button = (props: ButtonPropsType) => {
  const { children, ...rest } = props;
  return <button {...rest}>{children}</button>
}

let App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button style={{ margin: 10 }}>Sahil Kapoor</Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How should I define the type of my Button component so that VS-Code knows that my Button component accepts all the attributes of a normal React button element like style, onClick, className etc?

Answer (score 1):

you can extend your type from type of `HTMLButtonElement` class which allows all basic props of button

refer [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/#lib/react-dom.js) for all the flow types